# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException when using ObservableList?

Tags: javafx, concurrentmodification, observablelist

My JavaFX application shows a Linechart which is populated from an ObservableList which updates in realtime from underlying data model. This was working to an extent except I was getting ConcurrentModificationException due to different parts of the application accessing the List at the same time. Reading around, I saw that the List needs to be CopyOnWriteArrayList or ConcurrentHashMap to avoid that exception but it also needs to be ObservableList to load to LineChart. I later find that CopyOnWriteArrayList does not perform that well compared to ConcurrentHashMap. But then it seems counter-intuitive to implement the ObservableList using a HashMap. How then should one meet the combined needs of Thread safety and performance while using ObservableList?

Comment: If the `ObservableList` is the one used by the `LineChart`, you should only ever modify it from the FX Application Thread, since JavaFX is single-threaded.

Comment: If I've understood your point correctly, the Application Thread would be responsible for both displaying the chart and updating the underlying list. That being the case, how then does one achieve a good design with separation between view and model concerns?

Comment: Updating the underlying observable list should result in the chart being automatically updated, so it’s basically impossible to do those on different threads. On a broader scale, though, you would typically have a model class with some data representation. You can set up a notification process which fires notifications when the data in the model change, and update the view (observable list) in response. Your listener for the notifications can schedule those updates on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater()`. That frees you to implement the model to be thread-safe.

Comment: Another fairly nice approach is to define your model class to have an `Executor`, and implement it by passing all updates to the data to that executor (I.e. `executor.execute(()-> updateData());`). Then set your model up with an executor that executes all code on the FX Application Thread, which you can do as simply as `myModel.setDataExecutor(Platform::runLater);`. Your model is still completely UI-agnostic, so you still maintain full code separation.

Comment: Thank you, James_D. I need some time to digest your ideas but I'm sure they will help :)

Comment: I followed your advice and managed to get something working by having the Application thread continually checking the Model for updates. But it feels to me the Model should be driving updates rather than Application - there are times where Model updates stop but Application keeps needlessly checking for updates. I've been reading about Design Patterns and this feels like an Observer situation. Your Executor looks similar, could you describe that as a concrete implementation of Observer? Would creating an Observer pattern with bespoke interfaces be a viable option here?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I assumed your model would implement some kind of observable pattern. The executor is simple a mechanism for determining the thread on which the observers are notified.